# Oracle SQL custom data field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables that have QTY listed for a certain order number, TableA and TableB. TableB is a custom field that the user on the floor can input but is not required (so it rarely is entered).

when it is **not entered** there is no record of it in the DB, its not that its NULL it doesnt exist. So if i try and left join the tables or create a case statement it nleaves out the order numbers that i need.

example

```
    order number, qty, custom qty
      SO1234      10     15
      SO1235      20     (not entered)
      SO1236      5      12
      SO1214      8      1
      SO1215      2     (not entered)
      SO1216      4      2
```

What i need

```
    order number, qty, custom qty  **mu_qty**
      SO1234      10     15           15
      SO1235      20 (not entered)    20
      SO1236      5      12           12
      SO1214      8      1            1
      SO1215      2  (not entered)    2
      SO1216      4      2            2
```

Here is what i have been trying:

```
   SELECT s.order_bo, c.attribute, c.value, s.qty
   FROM wi.sfc s LEFT OUTER JOIN wi.custom_fields c
   ON s.order_bo = c.handle
   WHERE c.attribute like '%YIELD_QTY%'
   AND s.order_bo like '%SO1234%'
```

OUTPUT:

```
OrderBO:SO1234  YIELD_QTY   15  1.000000
```

If i change the order to one that has nothing entered like SO1235, it returns nothing.

tried using COALESCE below:

```
 SELECT s.shop_order_bo, cu.attribute, cu.value, COALESCE(CAST(cu.value AS varchar(10)), CAST(s.qty AS varchar(10))) AS mu_qty 
 FROM wip.sfc s, wip.custom_fields cu
 WHERE cu.Attribute like '%YIELD%'
 AND REGEXP_LIKE(cu.value, '^[[:digit:]]')
 AND s.shop_order_bo like 'ShopOrderBO:OR01,M646LC03EF'
 ORDER BY cu.value DESC
```

But the output is the same number (s.qty, no matter what i do, also, I had to add the regexp because the people on the floor sometimes put dates in there and other words not numbers like they are supposed to, I have no pull in that area unfortunately or i would change it)

How can i pull the Custom_qty column if it is there and pull the s.qty column if it is not?

I am open to any suggestions, I am still learning so it might be something stupid that i'm missing

Comment: Your title says "Oracle", yet in the question you claim "SQL Server 2012" but the query is clearly or Oracle. So which on **are** you really using? Oracle and SQL Server are two **very** different things.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Yes, that is my fault it is confusing. I am using a stored procedure within SQL server 2012 with oracle syntax. I am updating the question now thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `left join` looks correct.  Use that with `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT s.order_bo, c.attribute, c.value, s.qty,
       coalesce(c.value, s.qty) as mu_qty
FROM wi.sfc s LEFT OUTER JOIN
     wi.custom_fields c
     ON s.order_bo = c.handle AND c.attribute like '%YIELD_QTY%'
WHERE s.order_bo like '%SO1234%';
```

Notes:

- The condition on the *second* table needs to be in the `ON` clause.  Otherwise, the `left join` is turned into an `inner join`.
- *Never* use commas in the `from` clause.  *Always* use explicit `join` syntax.